# Include output of minify maven plugin in JAR

Tags: javascript, maven, jar, resources, minify

**Background:**
I'm building a JS library, which I'm packaging as a JAR file using maven. I'm using the [minify maven plugin](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/) to merge and minify the JS files.

**Problem:**
The minify maven plugin works perfectly when I use it within a webapp packages as a WAR. But in my case, where I have a JAR packaging, the merged and minified JS output is not packaged into the JAR file. I tried explicitly configuring the resources to be included in the build, but this works for resources under src (say src/main/resources), but not for resources that are already in the target folder.

This doesn't work:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.js</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I get a warning saying:

```
"[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!"
```

**Question:**
I want to package the minified JS files within the JAR, in the META-INF/resources 
How do I include the output of minify-maven-plugin which is in the target folder into the JAR? folder.

**Update:**
The minify maven plugin by default outputs the minified files to the target folder. I could optionally set a specific directory (within target) under which I want the output to be in. The minify:minify goal of the plugin takes an optional parameter 'jsTargetDir'.
The issue persists even when I set my original source JS as a resource. The source JS files get packaged into the JAR, but not the minified ones. The JAR plugin and Resource plugins of maven recognize only files under src. Since the minified files are not under src, but directly under target, mvn package doesn't seem to recognize those files.

Thanks,

Anand

Comment: How are the js files finding their way into the target directory? Assuming your maven package type is jar, are you using the minify plugin to process the src/main/resources into the target directory? Have you confirmed that the js files are present in the target directory?

Comment: Updated question with the required information

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the option [`webappTargetDir`](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/minify-mojo.html#webappTargetDir) which by default points to `${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}`.

Comment: Hi Samuel, what should I set the webappTargetDir to? Which directories within the target folder are packaged within the JAR?

Comment: You are not restricted to the target folder. You may set this option to any directory you want (e.g. `${basedir}/src/main/resources/`).

Comment: Hi Samuel, I tried setting the webappTargetDir and jsTargetDir as well. The merged JS files are getting generated in the ${basedir}/src/main/resources/ folder as set in the above properties. But the JAR does not include these files. The JAR only has the original source files. Why is the JAR not packaging these files? Am I running minify too late? The default phase is 'process-resources'. I tried the 'prepare-package' phase as well. Doesn't work. :(

Comment: Indeed it does not, not sure why though. However you can set `webappTargetDir` to `${project.build.directory}/classes` which works fine from the tests I've done.

Comment: This got me going in the right direction.  I am using MyEclipse IDE with maven integration and had to use <webappTargetDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}</webappTargetDir>